# Closest point to a line given 3 points with 3D vectors.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the plane containing the points $(-3,4,-2)$, $(1,4,0)$, and $(3,2,-1)$.
Find the point in this plane that is closest to $(0,3,-1)$.

I am really confused here. I can't seem to find the line equation for the three points, and am currently banging my head on my table.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say how much vector mathematics you know. Here's a method that is a little lengthy but uses very little vector math.

First let's find the *plane* (not the *line*) that includes the points $A(-3,4,-2)$, $B(1,4,0)$, and $C(3,2,-1)$. A plane that is not parallel to one of the coordinate planes is defined by an equation
$$ax+by+cz=1$$
for some constants $a,b,$ and $c$. We substitute the values of $x,y,$ and $z$ from the given points into that equation and solve to find $a,b,$ and $c$. So use your Algebra II techniques and solve this system of equations:

$$-3a+4b-2z=1$$
$$+1a+4b+0z=1$$
$$+3a+2b-1z=1$$

We get the solution $a=\frac 19,\ b=\frac 29,\ c=-\frac 29$. So now we know the plane that contains the points.

The vector from your desired closest point $X$ to the given point $D(0,3,-1)$ will be perpendicular to that plane. That vector comes from the coefficients we just calculated: $(\frac 19,\frac 29,-\frac 29)$. Let's multiply it by $9$ to get integer values, and we have $(1,2,-2)$ as a vector perpendicular to your plane.

Next we use that vector and the coordinates of the given point $D$ to defined the line that goes through $D$ and is perpendicular to the plane:

$$(0,3,-1)+(1,2,-2)t=(t,3+2t,-1-2t)$$

for $t\in\Bbb R$.

Finally, we want the point on that line that is in that plane. So we substitute the coordinates for the line into the equation for the plane:

$$\frac 19t+\frac 29(3+2t)-\frac 29(-1-2t)=1$$

Solving this, we get $t=\frac 19$. Substituting that into our line equation we get the point

> $$\left( \frac 19,\frac{29}9,-\frac{11}9 \right)$$